# Достать элемент регуляркой

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

В регулярках я не силён, поэтому прошу помощи.

Есть XML ответ от сервера, находящийся в переменной `$ustat`.

В этом XML есть элемент: `<ac id="1">Какой то целое число</ac>`

Вот нужно достать это "Какое-то целое число" регуляркой, т.к. SOAP и т.п. ради одной строки не вижу смысла юзать.

Кто может помочь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В php есть **[SimpleXML](https://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php)** для работы с XML

```
<?php

// Для примера
$ustat = <<<XML
<xml>
    <ac id="1">Какой то целое число</ac>
    <ac id="23">Какой то целое число</ac>
</xml>
XML;
```

...

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($ustat);

foreach ($xml->xpath('//ac') as $ac) {
    $ac_attributes = $ac->attributes();
    foreach($ac_attributes as $ac_attribute) {
        echo $ac['id'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
1
23
```

**[Посмотреть пример работы](http://ideone.com/raaHmn)**

Comment: Он может протекать памятью, насколько помню, в общем, следите за сервером. Из аналогов все равно только XMLReader, с которым надо суметь подружиться.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = '<ac id="1">111111</ac>
    <ac id="23">22222</ac>';

if(null != preg_match_all('/<ac id="(\d+)">(\d+)<\/ac>/i',$s,$m)){
foreach($m[2] as $result) echo $result."\n";
}
```

Comment: @ReaGedCorp

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php

> Возвращает количество найденных вхождений шаблона (которое может быть и нулем) либо FALSE, если во время выполнения возникли какие-либо ошибки.

Я уж молчу про то, что нестрогое соответствие фактически приравнивает это к `if (preg_match_all())`.